# Ubuntu Cordova - Build com problema

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ubuntu

Pessoal estou subindo o cordova no Ubuntu 64, mas estou com problema no build.

```
[Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/boschini/Desktop/Cordova/ProjetoX/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error:
/home/boschini/Desktop/Cordova/ProjetoX/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Meu `~/.bashrc`

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

export ANDROID_HOME=/home/boschini/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_TOOLS=/home/boschini/Android/Sdk/tools
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=/home/boschini/Android/Sdk/platform-tools

export PATH=${PATH}:/home/boschini/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/boschini/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

Quando chamo android no console, ele abre o SDK Manager normal, consigo abrir o AVD, mas quando vou dar `build` no cordova, ele apresenta esse erro.

Meu android studio funciona, ja consegui compilar um projeto de widget que tenho, sem problemas, o Cordova que está dando zica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver algumas horas e muitos copos de café depois.

O problema ocorre por conta de permissões, quando rodei o `cordova build` sem `sudo` ai o problema nao ocorreu.

Então para não cair nessa situação eu dou sudo su e trabalho sem sudo com o cordova, ai nao deu problema.

Caso o problema persista, tem que analisar permissão de algumas pasta.